# MariaDB very slow creating table with result of comparer (CREATE, SELECT, INNER JOIN EXCEPT)

Tags: sql, mariadb, inner-join, create-table

System:

- Windows 10 64bit
- 16GB RAM
- Intel i5 4 Core 3,2GHz

MariaDB

- V. 10.5
- innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
- UTF8
- InnoDB tables

I have two similar tables with ~500k rows each:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    `column1` VARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `column2` VARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `column3` VARCHAR(2048) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `column4` VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `column5` VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `column6` VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `column7` VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `column8` VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `column9` VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `column10` VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `column11` VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `column12` VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `column13` VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `column14` VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `column15` VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `import_by` VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
    `import_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
)
COLLATE='utf8_bin'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

I'd like too compare both tables payload and create a new table with the result. It works with two small sample tables, but takes hours on the real data.

The first three columns are the identifier and columns 4-15 are the payload. I need a result where I can see the changes made to the payload.

For now I have this little query, which works in small examples:

```
SELECT 
    table2.column1,
    table2.column2,
    table2.column3,
    table2.column4 AS 'column4_new',
    table1.column4 AS 'column4_old',
    table2.column5 AS 'column5_new',
    table1.column5 AS 'column5_old',
    table2.column6 AS 'column6_new',
    table1.column6 AS 'column6_old',
    table2.column7 AS 'column7_new',
    table1.column7 AS 'column7_old',
    table2.column8 AS 'column8_new',
    table1.column8 AS 'column8n_old',
    table2.column9 AS 'column9_new',
    table1.column9 AS 'column9_old',
    table2.column10 AS 'column10_new',
    table1.column10 AS 'column10_old',
    table2.column11 AS 'column11_new',
    table1.column11 AS 'column11_old',
    table2.column12 AS 'column12_new',
    table1.column12 AS 'column12_old',
    table2.column13 AS 'column13n_new',
    table1.column13 AS 'column13_old',
    table2.column14 AS 'column14_new',
    table1.column14 AS 'column14_old',
    table2.column15 AS 'column15_new',
    table1.column15 AS 'column15_old'
    
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1 
    ON 
    table2.column2 = table1.column2 
    AND 
    table2.column3 = table1.column3
    
EXCEPT
SELECT 

    table1.column1,
    table1.column2,
    table1.column3,
    table1.column4,
    table1.column4,
    table1.column5,
    table1.column5,
    table1.column6,
    table1.column6,
    table1.column7,
    table1.column7,
    table1.column8,
    table1.column8,
    table1.column9,
    table1.column9,
    table1.column10,
    table1.column10,
    table1.column11,
    table1.column11,
    table1.column12,
    table1.column12,
    table1.column13,
    table1.column13,
    table1.column14,
    table1.column14,
    table1.column15,
    table1.column15
    
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 
    ON 
    table1.column2 = table2.column2 
    AND
    table1.column3 = table2.column3;
```

I'm running the query on the host for now.

- CPU is on 30-40% on all cores
- RAM is on total 4GB
- HDD is on 1%

First of all I'm not sure if an index on row 1-3 would make the performance better, but I'll try that tomorrow.
Is there an easier way to get that result? I think I'm on the wrong way, but don't have a clue on doing it right.

---

EDIT

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
`column1` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_general_cs',
`column2` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_general_cs',
`column3` VARCHAR(1300) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_general_cs',
`column4` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
`column5` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
`column6` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
`column7` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
`column8` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
`column9` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
`column10` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
`column11` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
`column12` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
`column13` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
`column14` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
`column15` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
`import_by` VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
`import_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
)
COLLATE='utf8_bin'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

I cleared out all not boolean values (~100k rows) and changed collate. column2 and column3 are now in one fulltext index.

EDIT2:

So I tried now the changes with smaller datasets.

**FULLTEXT Key**:

- 10k rows took 36s
- 20k rows took already 135s

**KEY**:

- 20k rows took 5s
- 100k rows took 27s

EXPLAIN (withoug the CREATE TABLE 'xyz') delivers me this result:

[image]

I try to rethink my process. I don't expect 1s, but maybe it can still be faster?

Comment: Mysql does not have except operator, so this question is not applicable to mysql.

Comment: Please provide the `EXPLAIN` for the queries.

Comment: I will do the EXPLAIN tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

```
INDEX(column2, column3)   -- (in either order)
```

However, that index is probably too large.  In that case, have

```
INDEX(column2, column3(500))  -- in THAT order
```

Please rethink the sizes and charset of the columns.  If they don't need to be as big as they are, then consider shrinking them.  In particular, if `column3` can be latin1 or ascii, then the prefixing is not needed.  There is a 3072 *byte* limit on indexes; the `2048` is *characters*, which equates to 6148 *bytes* for utf8.

Are the (32) columns a UUID or hash?  This could lead to performance issues.  Provide more info, and I will discuss further.

Comment: Optimized the table and created the index als fulltext. column1-3 are VARCHAR and are kind of groups. I was thinking of creating a primary key for (column1, column2, column3), but I don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: @cr4nk89 - A `PRIMARY KEY` must be unique and `NOT NULL`.  Its primary purpose is to uniquely identify each row.  Its _secondary_ purpose is to be an index.  Do you have no PK now?  If `FULLTEXT` and `MATCH...AGAINST` works well with column3 (or the combo of col2 and col3), then that is likely to be a good choice.  Can you give us more clues of what is in the columns?

Comment: I tried it with PK and without. No difference in the time it takes. Col1-3 are kind of unique keys containing {a-Z and ; and , and - and | and 0-9}. Col4-15 are now only true,false,null. Col16-17 have been deleted. Time is now at 70s.